# Anyway to improve performance of SQL query to find rows with order by tag match count

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

**Server**: `10.3.27-MariaDB-log`

I have table of items and many-to-many table of item tags. In the search form I list all the tags that I want to find and expect to receive the ordered list of item ids with tags count in descending order. Nothing unusual.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2283235
;
```

**Item** table contains more than 2M rows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `item_tag` (
    `item_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tag_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX `fk_item_tag_tag_idx` (`tag_id`),
    INDEX `fk_item_tag_item_idx` (`item_id`),
    INDEX `tid_iid_idx` (`tag_id`, `item_id`),
    INDEX `iid_tid_idx` (`item_id`, `tag_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Item_tag** table as of now contains more than 60M rows.

After some struggling to find best query I ended up with 2 solutions which works almost the same in terms of speed:

```sql
SELECT 
    i.`id`, 
    counter.cnt
FROM `item` i
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
        it.item_id,
        COUNT(it.item_id) AS cnt
    FROM 
        item_tag it
    WHERE
        it.tag_id IN (3733, 5203, 5202, 1234) << --- test TAG_IDs
    GROUP BY 
        it.item_id
    ORDER BY NULL
) counter ON counter.item_id = i.id
ORDER BY
    counter.cnt DESC, i.id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

executed in **4,118 sec**.

and

```sql
SELECT
    it.item_id,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM item_tag it
INNER JOIN item i ON i.id = it.item_id 
WHERE
    it.tag_id IN (3733, 5203, 5202, 1234)
GROUP BY
    it.item_id
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC,
    it.item_id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

executed in **3,386 sec**.

Execution time of the queries largely depends on how frequent specified tag is. Previous times were for the following tags and counts:

```
| tag_id   | counter (number of items) |
| -------- | ------- |
| 3733     | 457357  |
| 5203     | 14300   |
| 5202     | 13803   |
| 1234     | 0       |
```

But if I repeat those queries for more popular tags my query execution time rocket to the 40-50 seconds:

```
| tag_id   | counter (number of items) |
| -------- | ------- |
| 3927     | 497732  |
| 4189     | 472916  |
| 3714     | 505325  |
| 3702     | 369115  |
```

1st type query explain:

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
--|------|-----|-----|-------|---|-------|--|---|------
1|PRIMARY|<derived2>|ALL|\N|\N|\N|\N|3271866|Using temporary| Using filesort
1|PRIMARY|i|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|counter.item_id|1|
2|DERIVED|it|range|fk_item_tag_tag_idx,tid_iid_idx|tid_iid_idx|4|\N|3271866|Using where| Using index| Using temporary
```

2nd type query explain:

```
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
--|------|-----|-----|-------|---|-------|--|---|------
1|SIMPLE|it|range|fk_item_tag_tag_idx,fk_item_tag_item_idx,tid_iid_idx,pid_kid_idx|tid_iid_idx|4|\N|3271866|Using where| Using index| Using temporary| Using filesort
1|SIMPLE|i|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|lm2.it.item_id|1|Using index
```

As you may have guessed :) this time is unacceptable to me. I wonder what type of optimization can be done to reduce query execution time?

**UPDATE 2**
There is another table 'TAG':

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tag` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `last_assigned` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `tag_UNIQUE` (`tag`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=372469;
```

I have tested additional queries from ysth's answer and execution time dropped from 44.563 seconds -> 38.922 -> 33.931.

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | it | range | fk_item_tag_tag_idx,tid_iid_idx | tid_iid_idx | 4 | \N | 3271866 | Using where | Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE | PRIMARY | 4 | lm2.it.tag_id | 1 | Using index |

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ALL | \N | \N | \N | \N | 2 | Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | it | ref | fk_item_tag_tag_idx,tid_iid_idx | tid_iid_idx | tid_iid_idx | 4 | t.id | 105 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | No tables used |
| 3 | UNION | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | No tables used |
| 4 | UNION | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | No tables used |
| 5 | UNION | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | \N | No tables used |

Anyway, it seems like there is no way to speed up execution time until I narrow down the search by adding new conditions. I can hardly think of a better way to shrink the search scope.

- Limit the search query by time column (i.e. show me last year items)
- Does not allow user to search for several most popular tags at once
- ... ?

Comment: As an aside, note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: ordering on the result of a `count()` is hard to improve...  I tried to create a [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94c0ad800a696fa73122606b3f4ce6fa) but results are too good to improve.... 

Comment: Your timings fail to include acquiring this list:  `it.tag_id IN (3733, 5203, 5202, 1234)`; my Answer eliminates that overhead.

Comment: what does `select version();` say?

Comment: 10.3.27-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 2):

The query is going to have to read all the item_tag records for your selected tags, and so will take longer for more popular tags; there's no way around that.

Unless you have item_id values in item_tag that are not in item that you need to exclude, there is no need to join item at all.

You may see some improvement from using the tag table (that I assume exists, because of the fk_item_tag_tag_idx index); this should change index lookup on item_tag from range to ref:

```
select it.item_id, count(*)
from tag t
join item_tag it on t.id=it.tag_id
where t.id in (3733, 5203, 5202, 1234)
group by it.item_id order by count(*) desc, it.item_id desc limit 50
```

If there is no tag table, you can instead use an ad-hoc table:

```
select it.item_id, count(*)
from (select 3733 id union all select 5203 union all select 5202 union all select 1234) t
join item_tag it on t.id=it.tag_id
group by it.item_id order by count(*) desc, it.item_id desc limit 50
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, there is also a table of TAGs. I just didn't mention it because I thought it doesn't matter. I updated the original post with the new measurements. Your queries did reduced the execution time and I cannot understand why. Why using additional table made query run faster?

Comment: If the two explains after `-> 38.922 -> 33.931.` are from my two queries, it looks like the improvement for the first one is just not having to read the item table; it is still reading first from item_tag with a range instead of reading tag first and then item_tag with a reference.  Try adding straight_join to my first query `select straight_join it.item_id, count(*) ...`

Comment: 'SELECT straight_join' query completed in 49 min 44 sec :) vs 42 sec.
Here is explain:
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
1|SIMPLE|t|index|PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE|id_UNIQUE|4|\N|330728|Using index| Using temporary| Using filesort
1|SIMPLE|it|ref|fk_item_tag_tag_idx,tid_iid_idx|tid_iid_idx|tid_iid_idx|4|lm2.t.id|104|Using where| Using index

Answer (score 1):

DROP these, they hurt performance:

```
INDEX `fk_item_tag_tag_idx` (`tag_id`),
INDEX `fk_item_tag_item_idx` (`item_id`),
```

They get in the way of the Optimizer realizing that one of the composite indexes is better.

What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Every InnoDB must have a PK, and it is better to explicitly state the PK.  If the combination `(tag_id, item_id)`, then make it the PK.  (But don't bother making `(item_id, tag_id)` Unique.)

What do the tags look like?  Are they short strings?  If so, do not bother having an `id` for each tag.  Simply put the string in this table.

Further discussion: [*many:many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)  And, I speak from experience on tagging.

Also, get rid of the nested `SELECT`.  Finding the most common tags is simply:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM tags
    WHERE tag IN (...)
    GROUP BY tag
    ORDER BY counter DESC
    LIMIT 50;
```

(Yes, you could tack on `tag` to the `ORDER BY`.)

Comment: I removed single column indexes like you suggested but in terms of speed nothing changed. I dont have PK on this table but I do have covering indexes tid_iid_idx (tag, item) and iid_tid_idx (item, tag). Isnt it the same? Anyway I will try to create PK. Do I have to remove covering index after PK created? Tags are just words, some of them are short, some are long.

Comment: The PK can be 'composite'.  A PK is Unique and is an index.  "Tags may be long" -- Even if some are, say, 100 characters, my advice stands.